# Do we need a "decoupled" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Several times already there where questions dealing with the REST API or the JSON:API I found to be good candidates to be tagged [decoupled](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decoupled). But we don't have a tag for that by now, or do we?

[decoupled](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decoupled) also seems to be a quite generic term for otherwise introducing [rest-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-api), [json-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json-api), [graphql](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphql) instead. Or would it even be the better choice to create those tags as well?

Possible [decoupled](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decoupled) candidates:

- [Using REST to create user with CAS username](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283445/using-rest-to-create-user-with-cas-username)
- [File upload via REST returns 403](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283430/file-upload-via-rest-returns-403)
- [How can I fetch the complete main navigation menu via JSON:API?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273091/how-can-i-fetch-the-complete-main-navigation-menu-via-jsonapi)
- [Output Paragraph values instead of the Paragraph IDs in a View REST export?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280618/output-paragraph-values-instead-of-the-paragraph-ids-in-a-view-rest-export)
- [REST won't work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63943/rest-wont-work)
- [Custom REST Resource POST problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237163/custom-rest-resource-post-problem)
- [Get nodes of specified content type with REST](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180861/get-nodes-of-specified-content-type-with-rest)

Comment: I strongly suggest we add this.  I have 20K reputation on this site and I'm having trouble finding tags when I ask questions about JSON:API-- that should not be the case.